# DeepLinks URL with firebase email verification. In firebase Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, deep-linking, email-verification

I am trying to customize the email verification template of firebase in such a way that when the user subscribe, the email verificaton is sent to him and when he click on the verification link,the app is opened and it handle the end of the verification process. I am using firebase for my backend. So when i change the default verification URL by this : 
`myappname://PageName?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>`,
firebase generate an error and the modifications are not saved.

Comment: You would need to add some code for us to be able to help (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The fact is that the problem comes from firebase console. When i configure the action url of  the email verification, by putting and url like this myappname://PageName?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>, firebase  discard changes.

Answer (score 1):

Custom schemes are not supported for email verification. Firebase Auth uses FDL (Firebase Dynamic Links) to send verification links directly to a mobile application. These use more secure mechanisms for app redirects including universal links in iOS, Android verified links and Google play verified links, etc. Please use these as they are more secure than custom schemes which anyone can claim and are particularly vulnerable in Android which is not as regulated as Apple via the app store review process.